# Should i launch an error or correct the values

Tags: algorithm, error-handling

Suppose we create a list class with a function that eliminates elements from position a to position b.

The class is supposed to be used by other programmers (like std::list).

Example:
list values : {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} and we call this function with (begin = 2, end = 5). 
This would change the list to being {0,1,6}

If the user calls the function with end > size of the list, it's better to just reassign end = size and delete until the last one or launch an exception like out_of_range?

Comment: Depends. Some languages do this kind of strange or unexpected behaviour (like negative indexing, etc.). I'm not a big fan of these things, sometimes you just expect something to go wrong but it doesn't. I would throw an exception.

Comment: **Throw an exception.** Asking your function to do something that is clearly impossible is the same as trying to de-reference a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question about programming standards. If someone calls your method with `end` > `size`, they have technically gone against the prerequisites of your function. It is possible the programmer called your function thinking it did something else, such as eliminated all list values in between the values they gave. If your function does not throw an exception, they will not know anything has gone wrong until there is a logical error later. The best practice if given incorrect parameters is to throw an exception, explaining what they did wrong. It puts more of a challenge on the person using your function, but it saves them more trouble later.

Comment: "They have technically gone against the prerequisites of your function." And therefore you should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

For input argument for rightIndex > list.size(), you have a few options to provide:

- ERROR: Exception (Array index out of range)
- WARNING: rightIndex is truncated to end of the list at Line 5:56
- ASSERTION FAILED (Error): assert(rightIndex >= 0 && rightIndex < list.size());
- Reference Mismatch Error: Reference provided by rightIndex is not matched with the function deleteBetween(leftIndex, rightIndex){ ... }
- Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV): Invalid memory reference and access violation, trying to read or write from/to a memory area that you have access to.